# JPA eclipselink sum of integer in JPQL are not integers?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I'm using Eclipselink with postrgresql.

My entity is

```
public class PedaneMovimenti extends EntityBaseGest implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   ... 

   @Column(name = "importo", nullable = false)
   private Integer importo = 0;
   ...
```

In my JPQL Named query I sum the column importo, then use this value in a costructor of a class.

I have two constructor for the class used as projection:

```
public SaldoPedaneCliente(AnagraficaPGF anagrafica, TipoBancale tipo, Integer saldo);

public SaldoPedaneCliente(AnagraficaPGF anagrafica, TipoBancale tipo, Long saldo);
```

The JPQL query is

```
SELECT new com.path.SaldoPedaneCliente(
                mov.mastro.anagrafica, 
                mov.tipobancale, 
                (
                COALESCE( 
                    SELECT SUM(m.importo) 
                     FROM PedaneMovimenti m 
                     WHERE m.mastro.anagrafica = mov.mastro.anagrafica AND m.tipobancale  = mov.tipobancale 
                      AND m.verso = com.bsssrl.bssstdgest.enums.VersoMovimento.IN
                , 0) 
                ))
                from PedaneMovimenti mov WHERE mov.mastro.anagrafica IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY mov.mastro.anagrafica, mov.tipobancale
```

The query is ok, it works.
I've a type mismatch in the costructor:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

If I change the subquery with a constant (1 for example), it works fine, but if I use the sum, I've the exception.

So, does the sum on Integers is not an Integers or a Long?

EDIT: I've tryed also `SELECT SUM(1)` but I've the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of "Integer"s is a "Long" !

I've changed the order of the constructors: first the Long version, then the Integer version and it works.